# Deploy winform application with sql server dependency

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, t-sql

I've a winform application that intreacts with MS sql server for database. How can I deploy the winform application in any computer and make it runnable ? I'm not clear on how can we deploy sql server database to the client computer and make the application running.

Comment: The easiest for you and the client is probably to use SQL Server Compact Edition which is just a few references and an .sdf file in the project. I assume you want each app to have its own database and not have them all connect to a central one?

Comment: Correct, the app will be standalone application and should interact with the database within the client machine. Do you have any links or tutorials on how can we do this ?

Comment: Google would be better than me for resources. If you know anything about MSSQL and c# then it is not much different at all. Many examples you find will be using Entity Framework but you can also just use ADO.Net. These are all google-able keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to SQL Server LocalDB (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx), which basically involves a changing your connection string and then deploying a copy of the .mdf file with your application. LocalDB will need to be installed on the user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

MsSql Server has several editions with different constraints and requiring different configurations (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions).

If you focus on standard, developer, enterprise, or web edition of MsSQL Server,
You need to deploy your database to a separate db server as a best practice, and your application connects it remotely by appropriate using connection string.

If you will use Ms Sql Express edition which you can deploy your database with your application together; in addition, you can prepare an installation package and attach the db to that installation process. You should keep in mind that Express edition has limitations such as storage.

If your applications is not stuck with Sql Server, you can take a look at alternative standalone databases such as sqllite. You can follow the thread for the details ([Alternatives to SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417917/alternatives-to-sqlite))